# Should a web page with a login form be secured?

Tags: security

Question in title, but I'll elaborate.

Say I have a form on a non-secure page, but I don't want the data that the user is posting to my web server to make sense to anyone who might intercept it.  Do I need to **serve** the form securely or simply *post* the form to a secure URL?

Comment: The only real consideration is if you want the browser chrome to show that the user is on a secure connection.  Some people feel better when that yellow padlock (and green address bar, if you want to splurge on the cert) show up.  If so, then the login page needs to be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By serving the form unsecured, you allow a man-in-the-middle to alter your form's POST destination, letting an attacker harvest login information.  But MITM attacks are not common, so you're probably fine serving the form unsecured.

Answer (score 3):

No. The post data is what counts. You can serve the login page over regular HTTP and post to HTTPS. You want the username and password to be encrypted, so we send that to the server over HTTPS we are golden.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need to serve the form on HTTPS. You need to post it on HTTPS though. For example the not infamous [Twitter](http://twitter.com/) login box is served on HTTP. What matters is to establish a secure connection when sending the username and password to the server.